# meta-annotation tags failed with extended transaction

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, spring-test

Application using spring-test-framework, spring-data and Hibernate -

I have created a meta-annotation tag and used `@Transactional` and in my test class used repository (say `userRepository`) to fetch `UserEntity` and this was successful.
Then I added code to fetch `userEntity.getChildObjects()` and here it failed too with the error `no session exists`.

Then I refactor the code to add @Transactional on top of Test class(instead of meta-annotation) and it started working. In this case, it seems test code is performed within transactional boundry but why it did not work with meta-annotation?

Comment: Please show us the full source code of your custom _composed annotation_ and explain explicitly where you declared it in your tests.